# Toggle multiple image show/hide

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I have 10 images that I want to toggle/show hide on click

I have toggled one image via CSS, but I cant get it to work with more than one because the label element is common.  I tried changing the label element to label1 but it wont work, I also tried adding a class to the label and couldnt get that to work.

The second image showing the checked/unchecked image of the tree is what I want to achieve for all 10 images I have.

I am not sure I can do with CSS? Any ideas or if not what would I need to do on jquery?  Any help would be appreciated thanks

Here is my code:

```css
#golf {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/golfunselected.png);
}

#golf:checked+label {
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/golfselected.png);
}

#naturaldisaster {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/naturaldisasterunselected.png);
}

#naturaldisaster:checked+label {
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/naturaldisasterselected.png);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p><input type="checkbox" id="golf" /><label for="golf"></label>
  </p>

  <p><input type="checkbox" id="naturaldisaster" /><label for="naturaldisaster"></label>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With css you can just use something like this:

```
label{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
    display:none;
}
#naturaldisaster + label {
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/naturaldisasterunselected.png);
}
#naturaldisaster:checked + label {
  background-image: url(https://www.thatsinsurance.com/naturaldisasterselected.png);
}
```

you will need to do that with every picture.

Comment: dont know why this answer got a downvote from someone, it works! I upvoted 1